# Autostart/restart program simply with daemontools in debian 9

Tags: debian, daemon, debian-stretch, daemontools

For example make vlc start and play a video full screen on boot.
After working this out here it is:

Comment: hi, is there an easy way to migrate this to unix stack ?

Comment: oh well, i will just copy paste

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435127/autostart-restart-435128#435128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need the following 2 packages if not already:

> apt-get install daemontools daemontools-run

This will install and get running the needed "monitors",
Then you need to create the "shortcut" to your program to start/restart automatically:

> mkdir /home/user/vlc-daemon /home/user/vlc-daemon/log /home/user/vlc-daemon/log/main
>
> gedit /home/user/vlc-daemon/run

put in this file and save it:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo starting vlc-d
export DISPLAY=:0 #needed for X program
exec setuidgid user /usr/bin/vlc -f /home/user/Downloads/myvideo.avi
```

This starts vlc program in fullscreen playing myvideo.avi as user "user" , adapt as needed.

Then, for logging: (add and save)

> gedit /home/user/vlc-daemon/log/run

```
#!/bin/sh
exec setuidgid user multilog t ./main
```

Make them executable:

> chmod 755 /home/user/vlc-daemon/run /home/user vlc-daemon/log/run

Now to install & activate service:

> update-service --add /home/user/vlc-daemon

Now your program should be running, and start/restart automatically. for more documentation see: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html

If not check log/main folder, and that you can also run /home/user/vlc-daemon/run manually from cli , also the following command can show some errors:

> ps -aux | grep readproctitle